# can't compare datetime.datetime to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

here is the problem:

```
print type(tim[i]),type(st[i])
sublist  = np.logical_and(st[i]<=tim,tim<=ed[i])
```

the print result is :

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'> <type 'datetime.datetime'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Che\workspace\excise\CCN\2014-10\VIS-reatract.py", line 64, in <module>
sublist  = np.logical_and(st[i]<=tim,tim<=ed[i])
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to numpy.ndarray
```

so,what shoule I do?
thanks!

Comment: You should fix the code. It clearly states that it can't compare non-compatible data types. You need to find the middle grounds.

Comment: What is data-type of ed[i]

Comment: when i change to  sublist  = np.logical_and(tim>=st[i],tim<=ed[i]), it works now~ but,why?

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD datetime.datetime

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD when i change to sublist = np.logical_and(tim>=st[i],tim<=ed[i]), it works now~ but,why?

Comment: Upload some list values of `tim`, `st` and `ed`, so that one can better understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found the reason it is happening, it has to have something to do with which side of the operator the array is and the datatype.  If you use the numpy [comparison functions instead](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#comparison-functions), it will work.

```
d = [datetime.datetime(n,n,n) for n in xrange(1,10)]
a = np.array(d).reshape((3,3))
c = datetime.datetime(4,4,4)

>>> a
array([[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2, 2, 2, 0, 0),
        datetime.datetime(3, 3, 3, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(4, 4, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(5, 5, 5, 0, 0),
        datetime.datetime(6, 6, 6, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(7, 7, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(8, 8, 8, 0, 0),
        datetime.datetime(9, 9, 9, 0, 0)]], dtype=object)
>>> c
datetime.datetime(4, 4, 4, 0, 0)
>>> a >= c
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> c <= a

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    c <= a
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to numpy.ndarray

>>> np.less_equal(c, a)
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Or if you have the option of using `numpy.datetime64` the Python operators work.

```
>>> a
array([['0001-01-01', '0002-02-02', '0003-03-03'],
       ['0004-04-04', '0005-05-05', '0006-06-06'],
       ['0007-07-07', '0008-08-08', '0009-09-09']], dtype='datetime64[D]')
>>> c
numpy.datetime64('0004-04-04')
>>> a >= c
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> c <= a
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

Comment: thanks~ I think when directly compare a np array with other date, the np array must be in the left side~

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem mixing of types in the comparison.  Given what they represent, they SHOULD be comparable but aren't.  datetime.datetime has millisecond precision, pd.Timestamp has nanosecond precision.

Try casting to a common type such as pd.Timestamp.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=2, freq='H')
somedate = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1)
type (somedate)
>>> datetime.datetime

pddate = rng.values[0]
type (pddate)
>>> numpy.datetime64

pddate > somedate
>>> TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to long

pd.Timestamp(pddate), pd.Timestamp(somedate)
>>> (Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'))

pd.Timestamp(pddate) < pd.Timestamp(somedate)
>>> True

pd.Timestamp(pddate) > pd.Timestamp(somedate)
>>> False
```